# Error:Cause: invalid stream header: 30303064

Tags: android

Project was running fine in emulator but suddenly after restarting the system I started getting error "Error:Cause: invalid stream header: 30303064". How do I resolve this?

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deleting .gradle folder from home and restarting again worked for me. After restarting the project .gradle file gets created automatically.